# Repleace the penultimate sign

Tags: javascript, string, jquery-ui, replace, substr

how can i remove the penultimate sign from a string?

**for example**

```
string = '96+658-+';<br />
fixInput(string);

function fixInput(string) {

  // string= string.replace(/[-+x÷]$/,''); // wrong
  // string= string.,curValueString.substr(-2,curValueString.length-2) // wrong
  // return string;

  return '96+658+'; 
}
```

Comment: Are you really asking for the penultimate occurrence of a symbol? Is `a+b+c+d` supposed to become `a+bc+d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
string.replace(/[-+x÷](?=[^-+x÷]*[-+x÷][^-+x÷]*$)/,'')
```

There might be a simpler solution though. It is using a lookahead to find the symbol `-+x÷` which is followed by exactly one more `-+x÷` (somewhere, they don't have to be consecutive).